# Capturing the CheckChanged event in a ListView in an AlertDialog

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I have a Xamarin Android App where I am trying to present a list of options with check boxes and getting unexpected results.  I am creating a lambda event handler in the GetView method of the Adapter.  I was hoping that by doing it this way, the current item in the current call to GetView would be the one referenced when the CheckedChanged Event is called.  My Code is:

```
[Activity(Label = "ListViewCheckBox", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Checked { get; set; }
    }

    List<Item> Items;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        CreateItems();
    }

    private void CreateItems()
    {
        Items = new List<Item>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            Item Item = new Item();
            Item.Name = "Question " + i.ToString();
            Items.Add(Item);
        }
    }

    [Export("onButtonClicked")]
    public void onButtonClicked(View view)
    {
        switch (view.Id)
        {
            case Resource.Id.btnShowDialog:
                ShowDialog();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void ShowDialog()
    {
        AlertDialog dlgList = (new AlertDialog.Builder(this)).Create();
        dlgList.SetTitle("Questions");
        var viewAD = this.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.DialogList, null);

        ListView lvItems = viewAD.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lvDialog);

        QuestionAdapter adItems = new QuestionAdapter(Items, this);
        lvItems.Adapter = adItems;

        dlgList.SetView(viewAD);
        dlgList.SetButton("Close", delegate { });
        dlgList.Show();
    }

    public class QuestionAdapter : BaseAdapter
    {
        private Activity context;
        private List<Item> _Items;

        public QuestionAdapter(List<Item> Questions, Activity context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            _Items = Questions;
        }

        // How many items are in the data set represented by this Adapter.
        public override int Count
        {
            get { return _Items.Count; }
        }

        // Get the data item associated with the specified position in the data set.
        public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        // Get the row id associated with the specified position in the list.
        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        // Get a View that displays the data at the specified position in the data set.
        // You can either create a View manually or inflate it from an XML layout file.
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

            Item Item = _Items[position];

            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.DialogCheckListItem, null);
            }

            TextView t = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtItem);
            t.Text = Item.Name;

            CheckBox c = convertView.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.chkItem);
            c.Checked = Item.Checked;
            c.CheckedChange += (s, e) =>
            {
                Item.Checked = e.IsChecked;
            };

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

If I pop up the Alert Dialog once and check a few boxes and close it.  The next time I pop it up, extra boxes are marked as checked.  What is the proper way to wire up the event in an Adapter so that when the event fires, it acts on the underlying Item that is representing?  Hopefully someone can look at this and quickly point out my error, if not, I have a working solution posted here where you can see the results. https://github.com/JimWilcox3/ListViewCheckBox

Answer (score 0):

When a listview recycles views, all listeners attached to it as well. So if the checkbox was checked and has a `CheckedChange`, both will remain a part of recycled view based on position. So i reset the chackedChange by adding `c.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(null);` This code below should work for you:

```
 c.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
            t.Text = Item.Name;
            c.Checked = Item.Checked;
            c.CheckedChange += (s, e) => 
            {
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)s;
                if (checkBox.Checked)
                    Item.Checked = true;
                else
                    Item.Checked = false;
            };
```

Also try to avoid creating adapter again and again so always when you open up dialog another 30 items is added excpet if that si what you really want. And bug related to the first item too.